# flake8: F821 undefined name for a global variable

Tags: python-3.x, pep8, flake8

I've edited my script to remove all of the flake8 warnings except one:

```
/tmp/flake8.tempfile.py:535:26: F821 undefined name 'salt'

/tmp/flake8.tempfile.py:536:29: F821 undefined name 'salt'

/tmp/flake8.tempfile.py:554:22: F821 undefined name 'salt'

/tmp/flake8.tempfile.py:602:21: F821 undefined name 'salt'

/tmp/flake8.tempfile.py:602:32: F821 undefined name 'salt'

/tmp/flake8.tempfile.py:609:21: F821 undefined name 'salt'

/tmp/flake8.tempfile.py:609:32: F821 undefined name 'salt'

/tmp/flake8.tempfile.py:623:44: F821 undefined name 'salt'

/tmp/flake8.tempfile.py:646:39: F821 undefined name 'salt'

/tmp/flake8.tempfile.py:651:39: F821 undefined name 'salt'

/tmp/flake8.tempfile.py:654:39: F821 undefined name 'salt'

...
```

salt is a hashlib ojbect that is used by many functions. It is defined in the main section of the script (at the bottom) with the line:

```
salt = hashlib.sha512()
```

Before being updated with data. All of my other globals work fine, so I don't know why this one makes flake8 flake out.

Comment: but if `salt` is defined inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` and you import your module from another script (so that the `__main__`-stuff is not executed), would there be a place where `salt` is undefined?

Comment: This isn't a module. This is the main file that is run directly.

Comment: I explained in the answer below what I was guessing what's happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot for response, but I put the entire main section inside "if __name__ == "__main__":" and the problem magically went away. Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrapped the entire main section of the file in a:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

and the problem magically went away. No explanation why, but at least this might help someone else with this same problem someday.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file like the

```
# file_a.py
import hashlib

def my_func():

   ...

   if salt == ... :
      ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    salt = hashlib.sha512() 
    my_func()
```

then it will run just fine when calling `python file_a.py`, but syntax checkers will throw warnings because there is a chance that `salt` might not be defined.

For example, if you create another file in the same folder like

```
# file_b.py
from file_a import my_func()
```

then you will end up with `salt` not being defined as the part inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` does not get called because `file_a.py` is not the "main"-file.

if you want to define a constant, then you need to define it outside – preferable at the top of the file:

```
# file_a.py
import hashlib

SALT = hashlib.sha512() 

def my_func():

   ...

   if SALT == ... :
      ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_func()
```

but most likely, it would be better to avoid constants and use keyword arguments instead.

I hope this is what is happening. If I'm completely off, then I apologise, but you would need to provide more code in that case, it is very much a guessing game like that :)